# "Generate Database from Model" returns blank sql file, Model-First EF, Oracle DB

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010, oracle, entity-framework

***UPDATE**:*      **FOUND SOLUTION** See end of question.

I am somewhat new to entity framework and still learning. I am using VS 2010, Entity Framework 5.0 (Model-First), Oracle10g, and Oracle Data Access components for .net.

**Problem:** Getting  blank sql file on selecting **Generate Database From Models** from context menu of designer surface.

I have created two database connection:

```
 1. ASPNET_DB_USER (for ASP.NET scripts)
 2. MY_ADM (my account)
```

`
Here is how my edmx properties window look (*Please note I'm using **SSDLToOracle.tt*** believing this is the right tool to generate SQL file for Oracle db)

[image]

EDMX XML File: SSDL: Storage Models Contents

```
<Schema Namespace="LMSPriorToolModel.Store" Alias="Self" 
Provider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" ProviderManifestToken="10.2" 
xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
```

I don't think there is any problem with my Models. When I click "Generate Database from Model" from Context menu, I get blank sql file. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

**Error Snapshot**

[image]

**SOLUTION**: I managed to search over net and found solution for this.

As I need to generate scripts for Oracle DB make sure following two properties are set properly:
**1. Database Generation Workflow**: `Generate Oracle Via T4 (TPT).xaml(VS)`
**2. DDL Generation Template**: `SSDLToOracle.tt(VS)`

Hope it might help someone.